# Recursive quick-sort causing segmentation fault (not overflow)

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, segmentation-fault, quicksort

Please help me (this would be very handy for a school project due tommorow)

I haven been trying to implement a recursive quick-sort algorithm in C++, however, when i run it i get a runtime segmentation fault(windows):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void getRandomList(int, int*);
void outputList(int, int*);
void quicksort(int, int*);

int main()
{
    cout<<"Quick Sort example, By Jack Wilkie\n";
    while (true)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter list length\n";
        string pnput;
        cin>>pnput;
        cin.ignore(1);
        stringstream temp;
        temp << pnput;
        int length;
        temp >> length;
        if (length < 1 || length > 100000)
        {
            cout<<"INVALID INPUT! (0 < input < 100,000)\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Creating random list of "<<length<<" items\n";
            int *list = new int[length];
            getRandomList(length, list);
            outputList(length, list);
            double start = clock();
            quicksort(length, list);
            double stop = clock();
            double time = stop-start;
            cout<<time<<"ms";
            cin.get();
            delete[] list;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void quicksort(int len, int* list)
{
    if (len < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int low[10];
        int mid[10];
        lmid[0] = list[0];
        int high[10];
        int lens[3] = {0,1,0};
        for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            if(list[i] < list[0])
            {
                low[lens[0]] = list[i];
                lens[0]++;
            }
            else if (list[i] > list[0])
            {

                high[lens[2]] = list[i];
                lens[2]++;
            }
            else
            {
                mid[lens[1]] = list[i];  
                lens[1]++;
            }
        }
        quicksort(lens[0], low);
        quicksort(lens[2], high);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
                if (i < lens[0])
                {
                      list[i] = low[i];
                }
                else if (i < lens[0]+lens[1])
                {
                       list[i] = mid[i-lens[0]];
                }
                else
                {
                    list[i] = high[i-lens[0]-lens[1]];
                }
        }
    }
    return;

}
```

My debug program (dev c++, almost out of internet and cant get anything big) say that the error is on line

```
    lmid[0] = list[0];
```

however i cannot find any issues with it, it has the error as soon as it calls the quicksort function, i beleive the issue has something to do with passing an array, and i am fairly sure that the function isn't recursing and bloating the stack

in case you need it for debuging, here are the other functions i used

```
void getRandomList(int length, int* output)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    return;
}

void outputList(int length, int* input)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        cout<<input[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return;
}
```

Comment: my algorithm works fine now, and can do 250,000,000 items in ~40s

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved, too localized and won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see anywhere declaration or initialization of lmid variable. That would be problem probably.

Comment: That wouldn't compile, not segfault... But still, the remark is valid.

Comment: ill try to change that and see if it fixes anything, i forgot to rename that when i refactored the variable name

Comment: ok, that fixed it, thank you so much. it used to have a segfault, but now it seams to have disapeared

Comment: can i mark 2 people, that other person found a wonky exit condition

Answer (score 5):

Your exit base case is incorrect.

This:

```
if (len < 1)
```

Should be this:

```
if (len <= 1)
```

That is *very* important for stopping the infinite recursion of your program. Your fault happens because you blow through your automatic variable storage space (aka. the stack), consuming more and more of it with each iteration until finally ker-boom.

---

**General In-Place Quicksort**

As an algorithm implementation note, you're making this *much, much harder* than it needs to be. Quicksort is about partitioning, and done correctly, you should need no temporary storage outside of the temp-variable used for swapping elements. Use the library to your advantage. A swap mechanism is provided for you, namely [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). This *significantly* cleans up the code.

```
void quicksort(int arr[], size_t len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return;

    size_t pvt = 0, i;
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[len-1])
            std::swap(arr[i], arr[pvt++]);
    }
    std::swap(arr[pvt], arr[len-1]);

    // important: do NOT include the pivot slot
    quicksort(arr, pvt++);
    quicksort(arr+pvt, len-pvt);
}
```

This is different than your algorithm in some fundamental ways, and not just because it works:

- It takes the array as the *first* parameter, the length second.
- It uses `arr[len-1]` to keep the pivot value, not `arr[0]`
- It requires no temporary arrays whatsoever.

Apart from the choice pivot values (it should be random-based, not always in a specific slot location), this is the traditional sweep-parition method used for in-place quicksort.

---

**Iterator-Based Template**

Though overkill for your needs, the above algorithm can be extended to a general iterator-based template that is easily implemented using the C++ standard library.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>

// assumes T::operator <(const T&) exists for the iterated type.
template<
   typename Iterator,
   typename Compare=std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>
>
void quicksort(Iterator first, Iterator last, Compare&& cmp = Compare())
{
    // early exit on trivial list (zero or one element)
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type len = std::distance(first, last);
    if (len <= 1)
        return;

    // establish pivot, move it to end of sequence
    Iterator tail = std::prev(last,1);
    Iterator pvt = std::next(first, (std::rand() % len));
    std::iter_swap(pvt, tail);

    // run through scan
    pvt = first;
    for (Iterator head = first; head != tail; ++head)
    {
        if (cmp(*head,*tail))
            std::iter_swap(head, pvt++);
    }
    std::iter_swap(pvt, tail);

    // run through sublists. note: pvt is NOT included.
    quicksort(first, pvt, cmp);
    quicksort(++pvt, last, cmp);
}
```

This allows you to invoke this on any sequence container supporting bi-directional iterators. For example:

```
std::vector<int> data;

// populate data with values.

quicksort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Likewise, it can be used on fixed arrays:

```
int arr[N];

// populate arr with values

quicksort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

// or
quicksort(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
```

Finally, the fixed array example can be made even more straight-forward using a simple fixed-array-template wrapper around our quicksort implementation:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void quicksort(T (&arr)[N])
{
    quicksort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
}
```

which then allows us to simply do this:

```
int arr[N];

// populate arr with values

quicksort(arr);
```

Comment: changed my exit condition, i probably wont change my algorithm, but it now works fine, and it should be ok

my one works by seperating the list into arrays of less, more, and equal value to the pivot, runs quicksort on the more and less ones, then merges them.

thank you

Comment: @user2875636 Regardless, the temp-array storage is *not needed*, and it is severely limiting to the size of the sequence you can sort. the algorithm I presented above will sort an array 2 elements, or 200-million elements. I strongly urge you to consider that.

Comment: Add since this is C++, I recommend passing the parameters to your `swap` function by reference: `void swap(int &x, int &y)`.

Comment: @John I didn't even *notice* it was C++. If thats the case, throw this swap implementation out *entirely* and just use `std::swap`. Thanks for the spot-check. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: i have changed it a bit, still very similar to what i had, now i only have one temp array which i delete before recursing the function to save memory(and then i pass the pointer to the initial array, along with a start point and length)

Comment: @user2875636 thats fine, just so long as you realize you don't need it *at all*. The fundamental purpose of of in-place quicksort is *it's in-place*. No additional vector storage should be required whatsoever.

Comment: well, now that i have modified it, and fixed all my errors, it can do 250 million in ~37s, although that at that size it peaks at 1.5GB memory usage, and goes to a depth of about 100 recursions

Comment: @user2875636 Very good. 100 recursions isn't bad, so long as the local variable space in each activation record isn't overt, which it is *not* with the in-place algorithm. There are reams of articles written on choosing a "correct" pivot value you may also want to consider. Quicksort is, by design, susceptible to pretty terrible performance if partitions aren't nicely distributed. Another alternative is to use a much tighter algorithm on the tiny partitions. Insertion sort is *very* common on that regard, particularly on partitions smaller than, say, 15 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question.

A few weeks ago I was practicing with C++ containers and algorithms, and decided to implement quicksort. I am attaching my code not because it is particularly good or efficient, but I like the feel it gave me to using C++ algorithms to solve specific problems.

Maybe it can help you both understand the algorithm and its "functional" implementation using C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<functional>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<array>
#include<list>
#include<string>

namespace detail {
template<typename T, typename Iterator>
void show(Iterator first, Iterator last, Iterator pidx, int depth) {
  if(std::distance(first, last) <= 0) {
    return;
  }
  std::cout<<"tail depth: "<<depth<<std::string(depth, '\t')<<"[ ";
  std::copy(first, pidx, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout<<"]  + "<<(*pidx) <<" + [ ";
  std::copy(std::next(pidx), last, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout<<"]"<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename Iterator>
void quicksort(Iterator first, Iterator last, int depth=0) {
  if(std::distance(first, last) > 0) {
    auto pred = std::bind(std::less<T>(), std::placeholders::_1, *first);    

    std::iter_swap(first, std::prev(last));
    auto pidx = std::partition(first, last, pred);    
    std::iter_swap(pidx, std::prev(last));

    depth++;    
    show<T>(first, last, pidx, depth);

    detail::quicksort<T>(first, pidx, depth);
    detail::quicksort<T>(std::next(pidx), last, depth);
  }
}
}

template<typename T>
void show(T& data) {
  std::cout<<"[ ";
  std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout<<"]"<<std::endl;
}

template<typename Container>
void quicksort(Container& data) {
  using T = typename Container::value_type;
  std::cout<<"Before sort: "; show(data);
  detail::quicksort<T>(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
  std::cout<<"After sort: "; show(data);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  std::cout<<"working with vector<int>"<<std::endl;
  std::vector<int> vdata = {5, 10, 0, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6};
  quicksort(vdata);

  std::cout<<"working with array<double>"<<std::endl;  
  std::array<double, 9> adata = {5, 10, 0, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6};
  quicksort(adata);

  std::cout<<"working with list<float>"<<std::endl;  
  std::list<float> cdata =  {5, 10, 0, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6};
  quicksort(cdata);
  std::cout<<"worst case performance: sort a sorted container"<<std::endl;  
  quicksort(cdata);

  size_t N = argc == 2 ? std::stoi(argv[1]) : 100;
  std::cout<<"test on vector<int> with elements in [0, ..., "<<N-1<<"] shuffled randomly"<<std::endl;
  std::vector<int> ldata(N);
  std::iota(ldata.begin(), ldata.end(), 0);
  std::random_shuffle(ldata.begin(), ldata.end());
  quicksort(ldata);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled on OS X 10.7.4 using GCC 4.8.1. Sample run:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/g++ quicksort-functional.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out 
working with vector<int>
Before sort: [ 5 10 0 2 8 3 7 4 6 ]
tail depth: 1   [ 4 3 0 2 ]  + 5 + [ 10 7 6 8 ]
tail depth: 2       [ 2 3 0 ]  + 4 + [ ]
tail depth: 3           [ 0 ]  + 2 + [ 3 ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 0 + [ ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 3 + [ ]
tail depth: 2       [ 8 7 6 ]  + 10 + [ ]
tail depth: 3           [ 6 7 ]  + 8 + [ ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 6 + [ 7 ]
tail depth: 5                   [ ]  + 7 + [ ]
After sort: [ 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 ]
working with array<double>
Before sort: [ 5 10 0 2 8 3 7 4 6 ]
tail depth: 1   [ 4 3 0 2 ]  + 5 + [ 10 7 6 8 ]
tail depth: 2       [ 2 3 0 ]  + 4 + [ ]
tail depth: 3           [ 0 ]  + 2 + [ 3 ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 0 + [ ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 3 + [ ]
tail depth: 2       [ 8 7 6 ]  + 10 + [ ]
tail depth: 3           [ 6 7 ]  + 8 + [ ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 6 + [ 7 ]
tail depth: 5                   [ ]  + 7 + [ ]
After sort: [ 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 ]
working with list<float>
Before sort: [ 5 10 0 2 8 3 7 4 6 ]
tail depth: 1   [ 4 3 0 2 ]  + 5 + [ 10 7 6 8 ]
tail depth: 2       [ 2 3 0 ]  + 4 + [ ]
tail depth: 3           [ 0 ]  + 2 + [ 3 ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 0 + [ ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 3 + [ ]
tail depth: 2       [ 8 7 6 ]  + 10 + [ ]
tail depth: 3           [ 6 7 ]  + 8 + [ ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 6 + [ 7 ]
tail depth: 5                   [ ]  + 7 + [ ]
After sort: [ 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 ]
worst case performance: sort a sorted container
Before sort: [ 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 ]
tail depth: 1   [ ]  + 0 + [ 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 ]
tail depth: 2       [ ]  + 2 + [ 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 ]
tail depth: 3           [ ]  + 3 + [ 4 5 6 7 8 10 ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 4 + [ 5 6 7 8 10 ]
tail depth: 5                   [ ]  + 5 + [ 6 7 8 10 ]
tail depth: 6                       [ ]  + 6 + [ 7 8 10 ]
tail depth: 7                           [ ]  + 7 + [ 8 10 ]
tail depth: 8                               [ ]  + 8 + [ 10 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 10 + [ ]
After sort: [ 0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 ]
test on vector<int> with elements in [0, ..., 99] shuffled randomly
Before sort: [ 95 37 56 15 50 77 61 66 8 43 90 7 25 74 1 26 38 87 13 64 57 84 6 16 17 67 35 42 55 9 59 81 2 68 58 29 76 73 99 96 33 11 34 4 86 46 39 52 97 82 10 41 53 28 49 5 80 12 71 14 91 88 24 93 45 79 62 31 19 60 22 69 94 63 51 32 44 75 98 78 30 89 47 23 83 48 54 21 70 36 20 27 0 3 72 40 85 18 65 92 ]
tail depth: 1   [ 92 37 56 15 50 77 61 66 8 43 90 7 25 74 1 26 38 87 13 64 57 84 6 16 17 67 35 42 55 9 59 81 2 68 58 29 76 73 65 18 33 11 34 4 86 46 39 52 85 82 10 41 53 28 49 5 80 12 71 14 91 88 24 93 45 79 62 31 19 60 22 69 94 63 51 32 44 75 40 78 30 89 47 23 83 48 54 21 70 36 20 27 0 3 72 ]  + 95 + [ 97 96 99 98 ]
tail depth: 2       [ 72 37 56 15 50 77 61 66 8 43 90 7 25 74 1 26 38 87 13 64 57 84 6 16 17 67 35 42 55 9 59 81 2 68 58 29 76 73 65 18 33 11 34 4 86 46 39 52 85 82 10 41 53 28 49 5 80 12 71 14 91 88 24 3 45 79 62 31 19 60 22 69 0 63 51 32 44 75 40 78 30 89 47 23 83 48 54 21 70 36 20 27 ]  + 92 + [ 93 94 ]
tail depth: 3           [ 27 37 56 15 50 20 61 66 8 43 36 7 25 70 1 26 38 21 13 64 57 54 6 16 17 67 35 42 55 9 59 48 2 68 58 29 23 47 65 18 33 11 34 4 30 46 39 52 40 44 10 41 53 28 49 5 32 12 71 14 51 63 24 3 45 0 62 31 19 60 22 69 ]  + 72 + [ 88 91 80 82 75 85 78 86 89 73 76 83 81 84 87 74 90 77 79 ]
tail depth: 4               [ 22 19 0 15 3 20 24 14 8 12 5 7 25 10 1 26 4 21 13 11 18 23 6 16 17 2 9 ]  + 27 + [ 55 35 59 48 67 68 58 29 54 47 65 57 33 64 34 38 30 46 39 52 40 44 70 41 53 28 49 36 32 43 71 66 51 63 61 50 45 56 62 31 37 60 69 42 ]
tail depth: 5                   [ 9 19 0 15 3 20 2 14 8 12 5 7 17 10 1 16 4 21 13 11 18 6 ]  + 22 + [ 26 25 24 23 ]
tail depth: 6                       [ 6 4 0 1 3 7 2 5 8 ]  + 9 + [ 14 20 17 10 15 16 19 21 13 11 18 12 ]
tail depth: 7                           [ 5 4 0 1 3 2 ]  + 6 + [ 8 7 ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 2 4 0 1 3 ]  + 5 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ 1 0 ]  + 2 + [ 3 4 ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ 0 ]  + 1 + [ ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 0 + [ ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 3 + [ 4 ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 4 + [ ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 7 ]  + 8 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 7 + [ ]
tail depth: 7                           [ 12 11 13 10 ]  + 14 + [ 16 19 21 17 20 18 15 ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 10 11 ]  + 12 + [ 13 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 10 + [ 11 ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 11 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 13 + [ ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 15 ]  + 16 + [ 21 17 20 18 19 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 15 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ 19 17 20 18 ]  + 21 + [ ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ 18 17 ]  + 19 + [ 20 ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ 17 ]  + 18 + [ ]
tail depth: 12                                              [ ]  + 17 + [ ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 20 + [ ]
tail depth: 6                       [ 23 25 24 ]  + 26 + [ ]
tail depth: 7                           [ ]  + 23 + [ 25 24 ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 24 ]  + 25 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 24 + [ ]
tail depth: 5                   [ 42 35 37 48 31 45 50 29 54 47 51 43 33 32 34 38 30 46 39 52 40 44 36 41 53 28 49 ]  + 55 + [ 64 57 71 66 65 63 61 58 68 56 62 67 59 60 69 70 ]
tail depth: 6                       [ 28 35 37 41 31 36 40 29 39 30 38 34 33 32 ]  + 42 + [ 51 47 46 54 52 50 44 45 48 53 49 43 ]
tail depth: 7                           [ ]  + 28 + [ 35 37 41 31 36 40 29 39 30 38 34 33 32 ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 32 33 34 31 30 29 ]  + 35 + [ 39 36 38 41 37 40 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ 29 30 31 ]  + 32 + [ 33 34 ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 29 + [ 30 31 ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 30 + [ 31 ]
tail depth: 12                                              [ ]  + 31 + [ ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 33 + [ 34 ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 34 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ 37 36 38 ]  + 39 + [ 40 41 ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ 36 ]  + 37 + [ 38 ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 36 + [ ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 38 + [ ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 40 + [ 41 ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 41 + [ ]
tail depth: 7                           [ 43 47 46 49 48 50 44 45 ]  + 51 + [ 53 54 52 ]
tail depth: 8                               [ ]  + 43 + [ 47 46 49 48 50 44 45 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ 45 46 44 ]  + 47 + [ 50 49 48 ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ 44 ]  + 45 + [ 46 ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 44 + [ ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 46 + [ ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ 48 49 ]  + 50 + [ ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 48 + [ 49 ]
tail depth: 12                                              [ ]  + 49 + [ ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 52 ]  + 53 + [ 54 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 52 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 54 + [ ]
tail depth: 6                       [ 60 57 59 62 56 63 61 58 ]  + 64 + [ 65 66 67 71 70 69 68 ]
tail depth: 7                           [ 58 57 59 56 ]  + 60 + [ 63 61 62 ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 56 57 ]  + 58 + [ 59 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 56 + [ 57 ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 57 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 59 + [ ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 62 61 ]  + 63 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ 61 ]  + 62 + [ ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 61 + [ ]
tail depth: 7                           [ ]  + 65 + [ 66 67 71 70 69 68 ]
tail depth: 8                               [ ]  + 66 + [ 67 71 70 69 68 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 67 + [ 71 70 69 68 ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ 68 70 69 ]  + 71 + [ ]
tail depth: 11                                          [ ]  + 68 + [ 70 69 ]
tail depth: 12                                              [ 69 ]  + 70 + [ ]
tail depth: 13                                                  [ ]  + 69 + [ ]
tail depth: 4               [ 79 77 80 82 75 85 78 86 74 73 76 83 81 84 87 ]  + 88 + [ 90 91 89 ]
tail depth: 5                   [ 76 77 73 74 75 78 ]  + 79 + [ 86 82 80 87 83 81 84 85 ]
tail depth: 6                       [ 75 74 73 ]  + 76 + [ 78 77 ]
tail depth: 7                           [ 73 74 ]  + 75 + [ ]
tail depth: 8                               [ ]  + 73 + [ 74 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 74 + [ ]
tail depth: 7                           [ 77 ]  + 78 + [ ]
tail depth: 8                               [ ]  + 77 + [ ]
tail depth: 6                       [ 85 82 80 84 83 81 ]  + 86 + [ 87 ]
tail depth: 7                           [ 81 82 80 84 83 ]  + 85 + [ ]
tail depth: 8                               [ 80 ]  + 81 + [ 83 84 82 ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ ]  + 80 + [ ]
tail depth: 9                                   [ 82 ]  + 83 + [ 84 ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 82 + [ ]
tail depth: 10                                      [ ]  + 84 + [ ]
tail depth: 7                           [ ]  + 87 + [ ]
tail depth: 5                   [ 89 ]  + 90 + [ 91 ]
tail depth: 6                       [ ]  + 89 + [ ]
tail depth: 6                       [ ]  + 91 + [ ]
tail depth: 3           [ ]  + 93 + [ 94 ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 94 + [ ]
tail depth: 2       [ 96 ]  + 97 + [ 99 98 ]
tail depth: 3           [ ]  + 96 + [ ]
tail depth: 3           [ 98 ]  + 99 + [ ]
tail depth: 4               [ ]  + 98 + [ ]
After sort: [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 ]
```

Comment: I had to +1 this just for the predicate binding to the first value in the sequence. The things you can do with that idiom are pretty kewl sometimes. And it makes perfect sense when using the canned `std::partition` algorithm.

Comment: Thanks --- yes, powerful idiom