# QuickSort doesnt sort .... C

Tags: c, quicksort

Why doesn't my `QuickSort` work properly? Meaning it doesn't sort out the values from the array. Here's is my output for a simple 5-elements array:

unsorted array, it's OK then:

```
A[0] = 8
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 45
A[3] = 78
A[4] = 234
```

but this is a sorted array, at least according to my code :

```
A[0] = 8
A[1] = 234
A[2] = 45
A[3] = 78
A[4] = 1
```

and the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void printOutAnArray(int *A, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, A[i]);
    }
}

void swap(int *i, int *j)
{
    int t = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = t;
}

int partition(int A[], int p, int r)
{
    int x = A[p];
    int i = p;
    int j = r+1;

    while (true)
    {
        do j --; while (A[j] <= x);

        do i ++; while(A[i] >= x);

        if (i < j)
            swap(&A[i], &A[j]);
        else
            return j;
    }
}

void Quicksort(int A[], int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        int q = partition(A,p,r);
        Quicksort(A, p, q-1);
        Quicksort(A, q+1, r);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int A[] = {8, 1, 45, 78, 234};
    int n = 5;

    printOutAnArray(A, n);
    printf("\n");

    Quicksort(A, 0, n-1);

    printOutAnArray(A, n);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can see without even scrolling down that the partition algorithm is wrong. You cannot decrement j, nor increment i, without knowing *first* that (a) the while condition is true, and (b) you've not exceeded/preceded the other index. Even that said, there are roughly a million examples of this algorithm coded in C on the web, and at least a dozen on this website. See what they're doing right, and you're doing wrong.

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger, and stepped through the code line by line?

Comment: @WhozCraig I also don't see a good pivot selection in the code. It's expecting the caller to provide that, and the caller just uses the element at `[0]`.

Comment: @Kaz: Pivot selection is not necessarily critical. There's no real evidence that, for example, median-of-three method is much better than the plain "take element [0] as median" approach. In any case the algorithm should work correctly with any pivot. At this point the matter of "good pivot selection" is not a critical issue. Once the OP gets his algorithm to work, he can proceed to experimenting with pivot selection.

Comment: AndreyT has already commented on several things, I'll add this only as info. There are typically two different schools of partitioning algorithms for quick sort : the *squeeze* and the *sweep* methods. You're attempting to do the former of those, and though it is *conceptually* better in that it can reduce the number of *swaps* compared to the sweep-method, it is also more difficult to both envision and implement.  For a sample of the *sweep* method, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349465/recursive-quick-sort-causing-segmentation-fault-not-overflow/19349900#19349900)

Comment: ...continued. And note that reducing the potential to reduce swaps is the only advantage to the squeeze-method. Both still have average complexity O(NlogN) and both are susceptible to poor pivot choices and/or specific data input configurations leading to degeneration toward O(N^2).

Comment: @AndreyT Pivot selection isn't critical if the input is randomized; but choosing, say, the first element all the time as the pivot leads to poor behavior on certain identifiable cases that could occur with high probability in an application, like data which is already sorted or nearly sorted.

Comment: @Kaz: Yes, of course. But this is largely a Quality-of-Implementation issue. And at this stage QoI issues are the least important of OP's problems.

Comment: Without droping a look onto your snippet, i can ensure you, that quicksort DOES sort in C ;) Also: why you explicitly note "In C" if you are using an own implementation of it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it does not sort because it is implemented incorrectly. Some obvious issues with `partition`

- The partitioning element has to be moved to the position *between* the partitions eventually. You never do that. I see that you use the very first element of the subarray (i.e. `A[p]`) as partitioning element. And it remains in the very first position. You never move it anywhere else.

  For example, in the very first call to `partition` you use `8` as partitioning element. But you never relocate that `8` from `A[0]` position. A typical implementation would usually swap that element into its final position between partitions.
- The conditions in those small `do/while` cycles seem to be tailored to descending sort. Were you planning to do a descending sort? Or did you simply mix up the conditions?
- Those small `do/while` cycles seem to be prone to array bounds overrun. Just think what will happen if your original array consists of identical elements.